# JSON response from SpringMVC controller is not working

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, controller

I want to response JSON object or array from Spring MVC controller. From these two [beingjavaguys](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/05/json-response-with-responsebody_31.html) and [mkyoung](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/) tutorial, i tried. 
I could success only in when the response is string. But when the response is in object or in list, it doesn't work for me.

```
//It works
@RequestMapping(value = "/angular", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getAllProfiles( ModelMap model ) {
String jsonData = "[{\"firstname\":\"ajitesh\",\"lastname\":\"kumar\",\"address\":\"211/20-B,mgstreet\",\"city\":\"hyderabad\",\"phone\":\"999-888-6666\"},{\"firstname\":\"nidhi\",\"lastname\":\"rai\",\"address\":\"201,mgstreet\",\"city\":\"hyderabad\",\"phone\":\"999-876-5432\"}]";
return jsonData;
}
```

Output is:
[image]

But the problem is in it,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "mkyoung", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON() {

        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setName("G");
        shop.setStaffName(new String[] { "mkyong1", "mkyong2" });
        return shop;
    }
```

It shows,

```
HTTP ERROR 406

Problem accessing /mkyoung.html. Reason:

    Not Acceptable
```

But if i change it `toString()` , 
It works but not with right output

```
@RequestMapping(value = "mkyoung", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getShopInJSON() {

    Shop shop = new Shop();
    shop.setName("G");
    shop.setStaffName(new String[] { "mkyong1", "mkyong2" });
    return shop.toString();

}
```

[image]

But i need JSON object or array of object as response. What is the probelm ? I have added jsckson dependency in my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

UPDATE:
Now i am sending request from angular js by adding

```
headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sublime.np.controller" />

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

As Sotirios Delimanolis's Answer suggesion.

```
$http({
            url: '/mkyoung.html',
            method: 'GET',
            data: id,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
            }).success(function(response){
                $scope.response = response;
                console.log($scope.response);
               /*  $scope.hideTable = false;
                $scope.hideButton  = false ; */
            }).error(function(error){
                $scope.response = error;
                console.log("Failed");
        });
```

But it shows same error.
[image]

Comment: Also, you can enable your DEBUG logs for Spring. They will explain what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `@ResponseBody` with a POJO type return type, a default MVC configuration with `@EnableWebMvc` or `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, and Jackson on the classpath, Spring will try to serialize the POJO to JSON and write it to the response body.

Since it's writing JSON, it's going to attempt to write `application/json` as the `Content-type` header. The HTTP specification requires that the server only responds with content types that are part of the `Accept` header in the request.

It seems you're sending your request with an inappropriate `Accept` header that doesn't contain `application/json`. Fix that.

---

Note that you are sending your request to

```
/mkyoung.html
```

Spring, by default, uses content negotiation based on some extensions. For example, with `.html`, Spring will think the request should produces `text/html` content, which is contrary to the `application/json` you want to send.

Since your handler is already mapped to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mkyoung", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

just send the request to the corresponding URL, ending in `/mkyoung`. (Get rid of the `.html` extension.)

Comment: I have added <mvc:annotation-driven />  in my dispatcher-servlet.xml. And where can i add application/json?

Comment: @Romeo In your request. If you're just sending a GET request through your browser, you can't do it directly. Open your browser's network console, find your request, change its headers and resend it. Otherwise, use a different HTTP client.

Comment: @Romeo You said you had jackson 1 on the classpath? Can you also show us your configuration?

Comment: Yes. I have posted it. See just before the update part of this question.

Comment: @Romeo Right. Update with your MVC configuration too, please.

Comment: @Romeo I think you need [core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl) on the classpath, not just _mapper_.

Comment: I have already added <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: @Romeo Oh. I just noticed you are sending your request to `mkyong.html`. I believe Spring uses default content negotiation based on some extensions, `.html` being one of them. Get rid of the `.html` extension. Your handler is mapped to `/mkyoung` anyway.

Comment: Yes. thats works for me. Thank you @sotirios 
Please update your answer... i will mark as answer

Answer (score 2):

Also add jackson core

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For List use method return type `Object`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "mkyoung", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Object getShopInJSON() {

        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setName("G");
        shop.setStaffName(new String[] { "mkyong1", "mkyong2" });
        Shop shop1 = new Shop();
        shop1.setName("G1");
        shop1.setStaffName(new String[] { "mkyong1", "mkyong2" });
        List<Shop> shops = new ArrayList<Shop>();
        shops.add(shop1);
        shops.add(shop);
        return shops;
}
```

Comment: Careful with this version of JACKSON!
it is not compatible with newer version of spring (4.x i think). You have to use: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.1</version>
  </dependency>